# Rigorous induction proof

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

Let there be a sequence $C_i$ such that $C_1=0$ and $C_n=4C_{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor}+n$. 
Could you explain me rigorously how to prove that 
$$
C_n\leq 4(n−1)^2,\forall n\geq1? 
$$

Comment: Do you know how to use induction? It works immediately.

Comment: No I need some help via that, I asked before but am seeking some clarification(prior question was closed). I am missing the example steps for it so cutting right into it logically isn't making any sense for me

Comment: Note: OP asked the [same question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/566498/discrete-mathematics-proving-sequences) a few days back.

Comment: I would encourage you to read up on the [techniques of induction / strong induction](https://brilliant.org/assessment/techniques-trainer/strong-induction/) first.

Comment: I've made this particular question look nice, but for future reference, we have a [quick reference](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) page on how to type up math using "MathJax".

Answer (score 1):

Strong induction would work immediately. The induction step is

$C_n = 4C_{ \lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor } + n \leq 16 (\frac{n}{2} - 1)^2 + n = 4(n-2)^2 + n \leq 4(n-1)^2 $

Comment: Wait, so that's the final induction step and answer? Simply input it in and since 4(n-2)^2 factored out is obviously less than 4(n-1)^2 thats it?

Comment: @joey Note the $+n$, so slight algebra is needed, but it's otherwise very obvious. If you're unfamiliar with how induction works, read up on it first.

Comment: so just subtract the n youre saying, and then from comparison that concludes the answer? i thought there was more to it

Comment: @joey The 'more to it' is hidden away in understanding how induction works. If you know how (strong) induction works, this question is straightforward.

Comment: so the strong induction is simply substitution in other words, such as in this problem. and you just subtract the n then compare the two factored statements?(for this case, want to make sure im understanding what you did 100%)

Comment: @joey No. You need to understand what induction is (as a mathematical proof). It's not simply "substitute it in". All I did was show the induction step, but you still need to figure out what the induction hypothesis and base cases are, and then put it all together.

Comment: such as inputting 1 for c1 base case which confirms as 0 multiplied out? and picking a n value greater than 1? such as 2?